# unexpected Nullpointer exception appears suddenly

Tags: jasperserver

i have a problem while trying to download the report from my application. Everything was working fine, and suddenly this error appears. even if we restart jasperserver the problem won't go away.

here is a screenshot that shows the problem; please help me, i really need your help with this.

[image]

Comment: Please check the logs under `apache-tomcat/logs`. There might be a more specific explanation of the error.

Comment: @BezWow It is a bed idea to repost the same question

Comment: @AlexK it was not on purpose, sorry